# On the sectional genus of a smooth projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $H$ be the very ample divisor on $X$ giving the embedding. Then one can write $\chi(X, \mathcal O_X(tH)):= \sum_{j=0}^{n} \chi_{j}(X,H) \frac{t^{[j]}}{j!}$, where $t^{[j]}:= t(t+1)...(t+j-1)$ and $t^{[0]}=1$. Define the sectional genus to be $g(X,H):= 1-\chi_{n-1}(X,H)$. Then I have the following questions:

$(i)$ why is it true that $2g(X,H)-2=(K_X+(n-1)H).H^{n-1}$ and $\chi_{n}(X,H)=H^n$?

Here I'm a bit confused as the asymptotic Riemann-Roch gives us :

$\chi(X, \mathcal O_X(tH))= \frac{H^{n}.t^{n}}{n!}+ \frac{H^{n-1}.t^{n-1}.K_X}{2(n-1)!}$+l.o.t

$(ii)$ Is $g(X,H)$ same as the genus of a general curve section $X \cap H^{n-1}$?

I can see that $(ii)$ is certainly true for $n=2$ provided we assume $(i)$ is true.

Any help is appreciated